How to build mupdf for java in linux?
Facing UnsatisfiedLinkError while building java code

I have downloaded the project from https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/mupdf
Next followed the following steps to build and run
make -C platform/java examples
java -classpath build/java/debug - 
Djava.library.path=build/java/debug example.Example document.pdf 2


First I got
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mupdf_java64


Then I replaced mupdf_java64 with libjmupdf64.so in System.loadLibrary()
After I got

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'int com.artifex.mupdf.fitz.Context.initNative()'`



I want to use mupdf for extracting text from pdf (which has multiple languages)
My need is to extract mutilanguage content from pdf as text without any issue in parsing if there any other tool to do this in java please suggest
Thank you!

There is pdftotext

@JoopEggen pdftotext works good for extracting text form pdf that contains multiple languages. I have checked this using command-line tool.
In addition to this is pdftotxt available for java?

Java can start a command-line tool, best with ProcessBuilder,
